# how to print/display cfquery with cfqueryparam values replaced?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfquery, cfqueryparam

As you may be aware that when we dump cfquery, it dumps the cfqueryparam values into SQLPARAMETERS of the dump. It's been alright to replace a couple of parameters manually. However, lately I've started working on a project where there are tens(or way more sometimes) of cfqueryparams being used in building the complex db queries.

is there a way to actually print a query with the cfqueryparam values replaced and display a valid sql statement on the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Has there been any plugin or a piece of code that I'm unable to find or it is never written?

Comment: If the intent is to run the query outside ColdFusion, Oracle SQL Developer for example, consider changing the order in which you do things.  Develop the query outside of ColdFusion and once you have it working properly, transform it to a proper cfquery, with parameters.

Comment: I inherited an app which I had to rewrite several dozen queries because all the tables and columns had changed.  So I went through the same process of dumping out the old query just to see the data being returned.  I had to manually replace all the query parameters manually in Toad for Oracle.  What I did was manually replace the `?` with the `:paramN` variable.  It was tedious, but the work is all complete now.  Had I thought about it, I could have written a custom function do to that for me automatically.

Comment: @DanBracuk That process works fine for when you're developing something new.  However, sometimes you inherit old code so you need to work backwards from the old query and dump it using a tool like Oracle SQL Developer, Toad for Oracle, etc.  So I can understand the need for a tool to do that automatically.  Like the OP asked, I'm not aware of a tool, but there's nothing preventing him from creating one himself.

Comment: @DanBracuk This is for something I need to maintain for already written code by someone else. I sometimes need to debug stuff (more frequent these days) where I essentially need to create the executable query to run outside of CF (example: about 20 or more cfqueryparam variables being used). Thanks!

Comment: @akashb As it stands, your question is currently [seeking recommendations plugins or an off-site resource](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which is a little off-topic for this site. This is why people are voting to close it. To avoid that, you should add the info you provided in the comments, rephrase your question to ask whether there's a CFML-internal way to do that, and explain the efforts you already put into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built in functions or code snippets that do this, but you could write something that works with *most* simple parameter types. The reason for saying "most* is that there are a few complications

1. The SQLParameters array doesn't include the original cfsqltypes. So it's not possible to definitively differentiate strings (which must be quoted) from numeric values (which are not).

   One way to work around that deficiency is to use the internal debugging service, which does include the cfsqltypes in its output. An obvious disadvantage is that it requires debugging be enabled, and utilizes an undocumented internal class. However, since this kind of task isn't something you'd normally be running in production anyway, it's an acceptable limitation IMO.
2. Unfortunately, none of the available options include cfqueryparam's `null` attribute. Since Adobe chose to treat nulls as an empty string in the parameter list, there's no way to determine when a parameter value is `null` and when it's actually an empty string `""`.  Sadly there's not much you can do it about that. Probably the best you can do is choose whatever default works for your application: `null` or empty string.
3. Syntax and supported data types vary by vendor, so any code will likely need to be adjusted for each dbms. Especially for less common or complex types like `refcursor` or `blob`.

   There's also the issue of handling single quotes embedded within string parameter values. Using replace() to escape single quotes should do the trick, but there may be edge cases.

---

You didn't mention your dbms, but here's a VERY rough starter example for SQL Server. You'll have to decide how/if to handle less common types like `refcursor and` blob` (currently returns "{{unhandled_type_(typeName)}}".

**Demo:**

```
queries = unParameterizeQueries();
for (qry in unParameterizeQueries()) {
   writeOutput("<pre>"& encodeForHTML(qry) &"</pre>");
}
```

**Original Query**

```
<!--- deliberately embed single quotes in string values --->
<cfquery ...>
   SELECT 
         <cfqueryparam value="1234567890" cfsqltype="idstamp"> AS idstampCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="100.50" cfsqltype="money"> AS moneyCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="6789.876423" cfsqltype="float"> AS floatCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="abc '1,2,3'" cfsqltype="char"> AS charCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="10.52" cfsqltype="decimal" scale="2"> AS decimalCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="abc '1,2,3'" cfsqltype="nchar"> AS ncharCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="abc '1,2,3'" cfsqltype="nvarchar"> AS nvarcharCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="timestamp"> AS timestampCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="123.964" cfsqltype="double"> AS doubleCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="123" cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint"> AS tinyintCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="123" cfsqltype="integer"> AS integerCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="12345.75" cfsqltype="numeric" scale="2"> AS numericCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="abc '1,2,3'" cfsqltype="longvarchar"> AS longvarcharCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="123" cfsqltype="bigint"> AS bigintCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="time"> AS timeCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="123" cfsqltype="bit"> AS bitCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="date"> AS dateCol
        , <cfqueryparam value='<AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person LastName="Achong" />' cfsqltype="sqlxml"> AS sqlxmlCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="123" cfsqltype="smallint"> AS smallintCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="123" cfsqltype="real"> AS realCol
        , <cfqueryparam value="abc '1,2,3'" cfsqltype="varchar"> AS varcharCol
        , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" null="true"> AS NullVarcharCol
</cfquery>
```

**Output**

```
SELECT 

         '1234567890' AS idstampCol
        , 100.5 AS moneyCol
        , 6789.876423 AS floatCol
        , 'abc ''1,2,3''' AS charCol
        , 10.52 AS decimalCol
        , N'abc ''1,2,3''' AS ncharCol
        , N'abc ''1,2,3''' AS nvarcharCol
        , '2022-04-06 02:33:16.59' AS timestampCol
        , 123.964 AS doubleCol
        , 123 AS tinyintCol
        , 123 AS integerCol
        , 12345.75 AS numericCol
        , 'abc ''1,2,3''' AS longvarcharCol
        , 123 AS bigintCol
        , '02:33:16' AS timeCol
        , 1 AS bitCol
        , '2022-04-06' AS dateCol
        , '<AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person LastName="Achong" />' AS sqlxmlCol
        , 123 AS smallintCol
        , 123.0 AS realCol
        , 'abc ''1,2,3''' AS varcharCol
        , NULL AS NullVarcharCol
```

**UDF's**

```
public array function unParameterizeQueries() {
    
    // store results 
    local.results = [];
    
    // get debugging service 
    local.svc = createObject("java", "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory").getDebuggingService().getDebugger();
    local.qry = local.svc.getData();

    // get all queries for request 
    local.allQueries = queryExecute(
        "   SELECT  Attributes AS SQLParameters, Body AS SQLString 
            FROM   qry
            WHERE  Type = :type 
        "
        ,  { type   : "SqlQuery" }
        ,  { dbtype : "query" }
    );
    
    // for each query, replace parameters and output sql 
    local.allQueries.each( function(row, currentRow, qry) {
    
        local.sql = row.SQLString;
        
        row.SQLParameters.each(function(param, index) {
            sql = sql.replace( "?"
                , formatSQLParam( param.value, param.sqlType, true )
                , "one"
            );
        });
        
        results.append( sql );
    });

    return local.results;
}

public string function formatSQLParam( 
        required string paramValue 
        , required string sqlType
        , boolean emptyStringAsNull = true 
){

  local.handleAsString = "char,varchar,longvarchar,date,idstamp,time,timestamp,sqlxml,clob";
  local.handleAsNumeric = "bigint,decimal,double,float,integer,money,money4,numeric,smallint,real,tinyint";
  local.handleAsUnicodeString = "longnvarchar,nchar,nvarchar,nclob";
  local.handleAsBoolean = "bit";
  
  // remove used in old versions "cf_sql_" prefix used in old versions 
  local.typeName = arguments.sqlType.replaceNoCase("cf_sql_", "");
  
  if ( emptyStringAsNull && isSimpleValue(arguments.paramValue) && arguments.paramValue == "" ) {
      local.result = "NULL";
  }
  else if ( local.handleAsString.listFindNoCase(local.typeName) ) {
     local.result = "'"& replace( arguments.paramValue, "'", "''", "all" ) &"'";
  }
  //For sql server, prefix unicode columns with "N"
  else if ( local.handleAsUnicodeString.listFindNoCase(local.typeName) ) {
     local.result = "N'"& replace( arguments.paramValue, "'", "''", "all" ) &"'";
  }
  else if ( local.handleAsNumeric.listFindNoCase(local.typeName) ) {
     local.result = arguments.paramValue ;
  }
  else if ( local.handleAsBoolean.listFindNoCase(local.typeName) ) {
     local.result = arguments.paramValue ? 1 : 0;
  }
  // Otherwise, indicate the type isn't currently handled 
  else {
     local.result = " {{unhandled_type_"& arguments.sqlType &"}}";
  }
  
  return local.result;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't mind getting the debugging on. The {{unhandled_type_(typeName)}} is something that I can improve on or altogether ignore in the case of QoQs. Thanks, heaps for this.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely will need tweaking :) Thanks for mentioning QoQ's. They should be treated the same as regular queries, because the types are always the same, but ... it wasn't doing that because the replacement of "cf_sql_" was case sensitive and CF does love to capitalize things! ;-).  Anyway, that's fixed now, so it should handle all data types except `refcursor` and `blob`.